# Apply css style only for mobile devices

Tags: css, mobile

I have a web app and I want for mobile only to remove the scroll bar from body element.

i have tried with

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
}
```

but nothing happend, the css property is not applied;

How can I set the scroll hidden only on mobile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you will need to add more details because it's working as expected (resize your browser to see it or check [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0978v5qf/3/)):

```css
body {
  height: 2000px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background-color: red;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
}
```